# Explicit construction of a finite projective resolution of a direct summand

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M,N$ be modules over a Commutative ring $R$. If

$$0\to P_n \to P_{n-1}\to \cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M\oplus N \to 0$$  is a finite projective resolution of $M \oplus N$, where $n\ge 1$, then how does one explicitly construct a finite projective resolution of $M$ without using Ext functor or without apriori knowing $M$ has  finite projective dimension?

Comment: Could you explain you how to construct one using the Ext functor?